# How occurs the enantiomorph of the mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection

How occurs the [enantiomorph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_%28mathematics%29) of the mirror?

I would like to know how occurs the RELATIONS OF THE RAYS with the mirror and the image, everything that happens to be flipped image from the right to the left.

Comment: Have you considered checking wikipedia for some basic definitions and formulas? Then you may come up with a more specific question.

Comment: Duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8227/, one of the highest rated questions on this site, so it has some excellent answers :)

Comment: That's good! Thank you for the link, I still need to learn how to find questions just like my question.

Comment: I analyzed all the content of the link, but have not found a physical evidence with the rays. How it travels and all the physical explanation with the rays.

Comment: @Kyle Non sequitur

Comment: @Babou fair enough, I should have said it has some of the highest rated answers, which *would* imply that they're actually excellent.

Answer (score 0):

From the link in the comments it should be clear that a mirror does not flip left/right but rather in/out. The mirrored image is flipped at the (surprise!) mirror plane. If you look at the mirror at an angle $\alpha$, you are looking at something that has the same angle between the perpendicular and the point where the "looking-ray" hits the mirror. This is independent of the direction in which you are looking. The physical explanation of the rays can be reduced to: Incoming angle equals outgoing angle.