# Mathematical description of a mirror

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

I have recently been thinking about some "paradoxes" about mirrors, such as [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/a-mirror-flips-left-and-right-but-not-up-and-down) .

Yet I still have not found a *mathematical* (or physical) full description of an ideal mirror (no adsorption, no distortion, etc.).

Let's say that I have a 2D image in front of a mirror: How can I can I describe it and how can I describe its reflection?

I suppose there must be some kind of operator that acts on it and I suppose it is a reflection or rotation of $\pi$ around a given axis; but what axis?

Answer (score 1):

It is reflection not rotation. And there is no axis for reflection but there is a reflection plane. The operation, in Cartesian coordinates, is (x,y,z) -> (x,y,-z) where z is the axis normal to the mirror plane. 
The mirror plane is one corresponding to the surface of the plane mirror.